# How to add two action based on swipe distance on Tableview SwipeAction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am developing a iOS 10+ app and in the new tableview api, it provides with the following functions for swipe action:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->         UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
```

However, this function only configure one swipe action. Is it possible to add two swipe action based on the distance the user swiped? eg. swipe for a small distance is action one, then continue to swipe, it will change to another action?